# Was the tree planted on the Whitehouse lawn by Macron and Trump later removed?

Tags: donald-trump

[This Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2018/apr/29/white-house-tree-trump-macron-vanished?utm_term=Autofeed&CMP=fb_us#link_time=1525021672) claims that

> Pictures taken by a Reuters photographer appeared to show that a tree
>   planted at the White House this week by Donald Trump and Emmanuel
>   Macron has vanished.
>
> The tree, an oak sapling from the site of a pivotal first world war
>   battle involving the US marines, was a gift presented by the French
>   president as part of his state visit to Washington.

The pictures shown in the article are not obviously of the same spot on the White House lawn, but it's not obvious that they aren't, either.  The planting reportedly took place April 23, 2018.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *the article are not obviously of the same spot* So then what is the claim?

Comment: @JanDoggen - I said it's *unclear* from the photos whether the same spot is portrayed in both.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Yes, it appears so](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-43941146). Multiple news sources reports that it is gone.

The reason appears to be that it's in [quarantine](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-france-tree/macron-and-trump-planted-tree-at-the-white-house-why-it-is-now-missing-idUSKBN1I00UY), also reported by multiple news sources.

> In fact, the tree, from Belleau Wood in France where almost 2,000 American soldiers died in a World War One battle, had been dug up not long after it was planted. It was put in quarantine, according to U.S. and French officials. The problem: Parasites on the tree could spread to others on the White House property.

According to the same news articles, it will be replanted as soon as quarantine time has expired.